# ReCaptcha and MVC3, problems getting Microsoft.Web.Helpers working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, recaptcha, mvcrecaptcha

I have reCaptcha installation problems. I already saw some posts about that, even in StackOverflow but it didn't help me to get it working.

I followed [this post](http://ihatethissite.com/blog/2011/02/27/recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc-razor-using-microsoft-web-helpers/), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666438/using-recaptcha-with-mvc3-and-razor) but in this line:

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers
```

I get the message:

> The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I added all references mentioned, all assemblies in both web.config files (root and view folder), restarted VS2010, updated the MVC3 package, included WebMatrix packages but I couldn't get it working.

I guess it should be simple to install, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a step by step guide:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project using the default template
2. Install the `microsoft-web-helpers` NuGet
3. In the `Index.cshtml` view of `HomeController` create a form and bring the `Microsoft.Web.Helpers` namespace into scope:

   ```
   @using Microsoft.Web.Helpers

   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       @ReCaptcha.GetHtml(publicKey: "__ put your public key here __")
       <button type="submit">OK</button>
   }
   ```
4. And to validate the Captcha in the controller:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
   {
       if (!ReCaptcha.Validate(privateKey: "__ put your private key here __"))
       {
           return View(model);
       }
       return RedirectToAction("success");
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Darin Dimitrov, I just wonder why I couldn't use this namespace in my app, I tried to download this you told me and it tells me is already installed, so weird. Thank you a lot.